# Get the text from a variable and show it in a QLineedit in a different class

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I'm trying to get the text of a veriable from a class A, and use the text of it in a `QLineEdit`to show it every time that the text changes in the variable.
Something like this:

```
class A(self):
  variable = None

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def get_text(self):
    self.variable = "Hello" #Every time that this value changes, it must be shown in the QLineEdit

class B(self):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def show_text(self):
    qle = QLineEdit()
    qle.setText(A.variable)
```

What i am trying to do is get the coordinates of the mouse, set them as `str` and show them in a `QLineEdit` in a `QDialog` that i created in `QtDesigner`

How can i accomplish this? Hope you can help me.

### EDIT

I need `class B` to be a `QDialog`. I added some changes to make it more readable for what i need.

```
class A(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def get_text(self, event):
    if event.button == 1:
      self.variable = event.xdata

  @property
  def variable(self):
    self.b.qle.setText()

  @variable.setter
  def variable(self, value):
    self.b.qle.setText(value) 

class B(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    QDialog.__init__(self, None)
    # you need to store the lineedit as a instance attribute of B so it can be accessed in A
    self.qle = QLineEdit()
```

Is there anything that i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your variable as a Python property so that you can run a method every time the variable is updated. This is also useful if you want to run checks on the value before storing it (eg make sure it is a valid number or whatever you feel like).

You can do this like so:

```
class A(self):
  variable = None

  def __init__(self):
    # you need a reference to the instance of the B class for this to work. 
    # dependning on how you create B currently, you might need to adapt this code
    self.b = B() 

  def get_text(self):
    self.variable = "Hello" #Every time that this value changes, it must be shown in the QLineEdit

  @property
  def variable(self):
    return self.b.qle.text()

  @variable.setter
  def variable(self, value):
    # do any checks you want
    self.b.qle.setText(value)

class B(self):
  def __init__(self):
    # you need to store the lineedit as a instance attribute of B so it can be accessed in A
    self.qle = QLineEdit()
```

If you didn't want to instantiate `B` inside `A`, you could instead pass in a reference to the line edit when instantiating `A`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @three_pineapples. Do i have to write `@property` above the method?. Sorry, I am new in python and I do not know what is that call.

Comment: @PabloFlores Yes, It is called a decorator. You can read about the property decorator [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17330273/1994235) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

Comment: Thank you, i learned a lot from here. I tried this and it does not work. I edited my question with some changes that i made for another attributes that i need for this figure.

Comment: Is there anything that i am missing?